# SELECT ... WHERE t1.tag = 'bob' AND t2.tag = 'foo' AND t1.idx = t2.idx on same table

Tags: postgresql, relational-division

I have a postgres table (idx int, tag varchar) with the data

```
1 T1
1 T2
1 T4
2 T2
2 T3
2 T4
3 T1
3 T4
....
```

And I want to do a query the return a result if both T1 and T2 are matched.
BUt I want a Variable number of T to match.

I can create the SQL at run time depending upon the number of args but can I do this using only SQL?

I have tried

```
SELECT t1.idx, t1.tag, t2.tag, t3.tag from tags t1, tags t2, tags t3 WHERE  t1.idx = t2.idx AND t1.tag = 'T1' AND t2.tag = 'T2' AND t1.idx = t3.idx AND t3.tag = 'T3';
```

This works. But what if I had 2 or 5 different Ts. Do I do this 5 times?

Want a return list of all idx that match the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using aggregation:

```
select idx
from tags
where tag in ('T1', 'T2')
group by idx
having count(distinct tag) = 2;
```

Note that the above would also return values that have additional tags. So the above returns those, that have at least those two tags.

If you need that for five tags, extend the `IN` list and adjust the condition for the `count()` to match the number of elements in the `IN` list.

An index on `tags (tag, idx)` will speed this up.

Comment: This works.  Now I need to write the code for node. I had a problem with IN before I had to use WHERE tag = ANY($1) ...), [set])

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? (this was done in mysql, but you are asking a standard SQL question).

```
select t.idx, t.name
from test t INNER JOIN test t2
         on t.name = t2.name
```

Comment: No, I use the idx and tag as the primary key.  I want to search on a list of values.  BTW, I have 46 million records in the table.

Comment: This is essentially the same query as used in the question (just with nicer JOINs). It requires adding a new join for each value to be checked

Answer (score 0):

a_horse_with_no_name answered the SQL question, Thanx. The JavaScript code is

```
 const seltag = "SELECT idx FROM tags WHERE tag = ANY($1) GROUP BY idx having count(distinct tag) = $2"
 let tags = JSON.parse(args[0]).split(',').map((itm) => itm.trim())
 pool.query(seltag, [tags, tags.length])
```